Crash issue in iOS related to fopen_s(__sFILE**, char const*, char const*)
I integrated Firebase Crashlytic into my iOS app and got this crash report from other user.

Looking at stack trace, I don't know what the issue is.
I'm also unable unable to replicate the crash issue at my own device. Does anybody have idea what should I check or fix?

Click o  keys and the logs tab you can sometimes get more info in those

You are not reading that stacktrace correctly;  it actually crashed in pb_check_proto3_default_value + 342.  Expand the arrow between frames 0 and 23 to get more context that will help you track it down.

Also perhaps this helps?

@Blurzschyter This seems to be Firebase dependency issue as highlighted in below to links.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/12632
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/11403
I would recommend you to update your firebase dependency to 10.28.1 version as mentioned by Firebase Team that this issue has been fixed.

